# custom image slider in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tryin to build a simple custom image slide and mostly make it work except one thing. When `:src` data changes, I want to add a transition like `opacity:0 ~ 1` but couldn't achieve that part. Here is the slide.

template

```
<img class="slide-image" :src="getImgUrl(images[0])">
```

script

```
data(){
    return {
        images: [
            "/images/home/home-slide1.png",
            "/images/home/home-slide2.png",
            "/images/home/home-slide3.png",
            "/images/home/home-slide4.png",
            "/images/home/home-slide5.png",
        ]
    };
},
watch: {    
    getImgUrl(){

    }
},
mounted(){
    window.setInterval(()=>{
        this.slide();
    }, 5000);
},
methods: {
    getImgUrl(im) {
        return require('../assets' + im)
    },
    slide(){
        let first = this.images.shift();
        this.images = this.images.concat(first);
    },
},
```

what is best and simple possible way to add a transition when `:src` changes every 5s, appreciate if anyone can guide about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Slider",
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        "/images/home/home-slide1.png",
        "/images/home/home-slide2.png",
        "/images/home/home-slide3.png",
        "/images/home/home-slide4.png",
        "/images/home/home-slide5.png",
      ],
      timer: null,
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  },

  mounted: function() {
    this.startSlide();
  },

  methods: {
    startSlide: function() {
      this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 5000);
    },

    next: function() {
      this.currentIndex += 1;
    },
    prev: function() {
      this.currentIndex -= 1;
    }
  },

  computed: {
    currentImg: function() {
      return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentIndex) % this.images.length];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Let’s look what we did here:

- We got an array of image URLs.
- Set `timer` to null and set `currentIndex` to 0 for showing the first image.
- Created `startSlide` function for sliding images every 4 seconds.
- Created `next` and `prev` functions for sliding to the previous or the next image. According to the last `currentImg` function it detects which image must show at that time based on the index.

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition-group name="fade" tag="div">
      <div v-for="i in [currentIndex]" :key="i">
        <img :src="currentImg" />
      </div>
    </transition-group>
    <a class="prev" @click="prev" href="#">&#10094; Previous</a>
    <a class="next" @click="next" href="#">&#10095; Next</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here we take advantage of the built-in transtion-group component that comes with Vue.js, then iterate images and add the functions we created earlier.

More details here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/create-image-slider/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `Vue-transition`

Wrap your transition section with `transition` tag like this

```
<transition name="slider">
  <img class="slide-image" :src="getImgUrl(images[0])">
</transition>
```

It will add classes when the elements enter and leave. So you can add styles accordingly.

Please refer this link : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components